# Mapping assembly code to VB6 code

Tags: debugging, assembly, vb6

I'm working on a legacy VB6 application. In a certain use case, the application fails with something which looks like a null pointer exception:

> The instruction at "0x2982e900"
>   referenced memory at "0x00000156". The
>   memory could not be "read".

I have tried to do some source code debugging, but I can't find the source code line which throws the exception. Is there any way to find the source code line which corresponds to an assembly instruction address such as 0x2982e900? (I have tried Reflector, but it only seems to support .NET).

Update:

When I debug the application with the VB6 IDE debugger, I don't get any breaks in the VB6 source. Instead, the windows error message mentioned above pops up, giving me the option to enable the Visual Studio 2010 debugger. If I do this, the VS2010 debugger displays assembly code like this:

> [...]
>   2982E8FA  push        eax
>   2982E8FB  call        29832E9B
>   2982E900  mov         ax,word ptr
>   [eax+156h]
>    [...]

The application uses some .ocx files from a company called Infragistics to implement the GUI. According to the [CrashFinder](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/bugslayer0498.aspx) utility, the assembly code shown is from the file `IGTOOLBARS40.OCX`.

Comment: Do you have the original source code for the application? (It seems like you must, as you say that you're "working" on the application.) If so, try running it from the VB 6 IDE so that the built-in debugger is attached. That should catch the error before Windows does, and at least report the line that's causing the problem. Updating your question here with that line should get you some quick ideas on how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like managed .Net code, VB6 code is prevented from encountering invalid pointer exceptions (because VB6 does not include pointers).

The problem is most likely caused by either

- A bug in a DLL or OCX (perhaps a third-party one?)
- A mistake in calling the Windows API. Most commonly through a `Declare` statement, sometimes through a type-library ([hard-core!](http://vb.mvps.org/hardcore/)).

The first step is to identify which line of VB6 code triggers the crash.

Either:

- Step through the IDE until the crash happens.
- Or decode the `0x2982e900` address into a VB6 source line number with [CrashFinder](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0498/bugslayer0498.aspx). You do *always* build your EXE with a [PDB file](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/05/11/pdb-files-what-every-developer-must-know.aspx) that contains [debug symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_symbol), right?

  To tell the VB6 IDE to build a project with debug info, you need to change one of the default compile options. From the File menu, select "Build Project1.exe". Click the "Options" button in the save file dialog that appears, and a properties sheet will open. Switch to the "Compile" tab, and check the box labeled "Create Symbolic Debug Info".

[image: Ensure that "Create Symbolic Debug Info" is checked in your build settings]

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but what is a PDB and how would I compile my executable with one (VB6, that is)?

Comment: @Brian: Updated the answer with more information about PDBs and generating them from VB6. This is certainly a viable path of discovery, but I think it's way easier to step through the code using the VB6 IDE to see what the offending line is. Walking through debug symbols is tricky for the average VB programmer, and I suppose why the option is disabled by default.

Comment: @Cody, @MarkJ, thanks for that. You're right, I think, about it being preferable to step through the code in the IDE, but it never hurts to have other things to try.

Comment: @Cody @Brian Thanks for the great edit Cody! It will be easier to step through the code in the IDE if possible. The PDB can be a lifesaver if you have a crash that only occurs on a customer's machine & you can't run the IDE.

Comment: I would turn off optimizations if PDB will be used to step through the code in VC (or other) debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reverse engineering the application using a disassembler such as IDA Pro.